# Can the spectrum of a unitary be made distinct by multiplying by a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Given a unitary matrix $U,$ does there always exist a diagonal (unitary) matrix $D$ such that $UD$ has distinct eigenvalues?

(Note this fails for general matrices such as strictly upper triangular matrices. It is obviously true in the $2$ by $2$ case as if you do not already have distinct eigenvalues, then the matrix is a multiple of the identity.)

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting the parentheses in "a diagonal (unitary) matrix". Are you looking for a diagonal and unitary $D$, or just for a diagonal $D$ and the previous interpretation is a suggested bonus question?

Comment: One wants the diagonal matrix to be unitary. However, since the diagonal unitary matrices have full real dimension, and having distinct eigenvalues for a matrix $A$ is an analytic algebraic condition (say quantified by the determinant of some matrix having entries $\operatorname{Tr} A^{i+j}$) if the result holds for general diagonals, it holds for unitaries.